# Azure feed: nuget package is not found

Tags: azure, .net-core, deployment, nuget-package

I have 2 solutions (2 .NET Core projects), the first one represents just the models and some simple services for public use, like email service, etc.
It's uploaded to Azure as nuget package and there is a feed which is used by the other projects.
So the link to it is something like https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/something/_packaging/MyFeed1/nuget/v3/index.json

The second one is the major project which consumes the project1 via this nuget package.
So for this purpose, I set up in VS the package source to the link above and then installed the nuget package :
Install-Package MyService -version 1.0.0-CI-XXXXXX-XXXXX

And initially it worked fine. But then I had to update Project1 (nuget package) and although after this, I consequently updated all the references for Project2 (Install-Package MyService -version 1.0.0-CI-YYYYYY-YYYYY - the package version was automatically changed) Project2 is not really working:
I can perfectly compile it locally and locally it works, but when I deploy it to Azure it does not pass the Build and I get the error message saying that it can't find MyService (from nuget package)
I double checked all the references and pipeline - it's fine. The references are updated and the pipeline just uses the feed name, not a particular version of nuget.
Please advise.

Answer (score -1):

- This could be the result of caching, which can be fixed by clearing the Nuget caches.
- Go to Tools -> Options -> Nuget -> General and click the "Clear All Nuget Cache(s)" button to clear the Nuget caches.